# Yii2 Auth Client for Google give error Redirect URI Mismatch after Login

Tags: oauth-2.0, yii2

I have encountered error, like images below

First i click login, the error not appeared
[image]

But when i login successfully, the application show error like this,

[image]

There is no mistake on Oauth Credential, but i think i miss a think.

This error appear just now, my application already run for 2 years

my scope on auth client is email..

Thank You..

Comment: Did you configure properly return URL? If yes, what happens if you copy that URL directly into browser - still same error?

Comment: @lubosdz this is my return url http://127.0.0.1/symphony/student/site/login?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.me

Comment: @lubosdz and if i copy it to browser it says "Invalid redirect_uri contains reserved response param scope"

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug opened:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/issues/241

Note that in the config you can set "returnUrl" => "...." so you can fix it without touching the code.
Probably there was some change from Google and now they return also scopes in the URL..

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem..

In Oauth2.php there is method called fetchAccessToken(), it set redirect_uri to 'http://yourdomain.com/site/login?scope=xxxxxxxx' using getReturnUrl() method, it adds scope parameter. I dont know why. so i set the redirect_uri staticaly and it works again.

now the question is why Oauth2.php is working fine before and now it produces that error? is there any changes somewhere maybe?.